# Mac OS X Energy Saver mode does not open or function

Tags: macos, configuration, operating-system, configuration-files, system-setting

I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.5 on a MacBook Pro. Recently, my Energy Saver mode has stopped functioning, and I can no longer open the Energy Saver Configuration Pane. When I click it, an Alert Dialog pops up with the message:

`Preferences Error`

`Could not load Energy Saver preference pane`.

I have attempted to reinstall the latest system update, and deleted

`/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist`

and

`/Library/Caches/com.apple.systempreferences`

However the problem has not resolved itself. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. The solution is to go to `/Applications` in the Finder, right click `System Preferences`, select `Get Info`, and check the box that reads `Open in 32 bit mode`.